# Find the function $f(x)$ under the given conditions

Tags: calculus, functions, summation, functional-equations

I need to find $f(x)$,

If $$ \frac{1/x_m}{\sum_u 1/x_u} = \frac{f(x_m)}{\sum_u f(x_u)} $$
$x_u > 0, \forall u$, $u = 0,1,2,3,...,U$, and $x_m = x_u$ if $m = u$

Could $f(x)$ be any thing other than $f(x) = 1/x$,

Is there any proof?

Or there is no way to know the function  $f(x_m)$.

Comment: What range $u$ are the sums taken over, and how are $x_k$ chosen?

Comment: $u = 0, 1, 2, ..., U$ and $x_k $ can be any value $> 0$

Comment: Is $U$ related to $m\,$? Does the equality hold for one fixed $U\,$, or for *any* $U\,$?

Comment: yes $x_m = x_u$ if $m = u$

Comment: Sorry, but that's obvious, and it doesn't answer the question. You said that `u=0,1,2,...,U` which means that $\sum_u \equiv \sum_{u=0}^U$. Did you mean $\sum_{u=0}^m$ maybe?

Comment: No, just there is a limited number of terms in the summation. There is no relation between U and m. The equation holds for any  U

Comment: @dxiv I think $U$ is a constant, $u$ is the index of the sum, and $m$ varies to give $U+1$ equations.

Comment: @BobJones The OP just replied that `There is no relation between U and m`.

Comment: @dxiv That is what I believed too, but I think my description is a bit more clear.